# blank asp.net site shows web.config error when i try to access it

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have created a blank asp.net website consisting of a blank default.aspx page, its .cs file, a login.aspx page and its .cs and a web.config. I'm looking to test .net authentication as seen in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) on the MSDN site. I've copied everything as shown in the article. I set up the site in IIS6 now when I go to the site I get the runtime error with the:

> *"To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off"."*

message. when I add the customErrors mode="On" tag to the web.config I still get this error like its not looking at the web.config. I've triple checked IIS and its definitely looking at the right site folder. Here's my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
 <configuration>

        <system.web>
          <customErrors mode="On"/>
           <authentication mode="Forms">
             <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
             </forms>
           </authentication>

          <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
          </authorization>
           <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />

        </system.web>

    </configuration>
```

I usually set sites up through CMS installations. This is the first time I've done one from a blank site in visual studio. Is there more you need to add to web.config?

Comment: ive found removing the tragetframework got rid of the error but left me with a resource cannot be found error instead :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set

Not "On" to see the actual error with stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

set

```
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

to see the actual error.

Comment: And debug=true in the compilation line to see the full stack trace

Comment: And remember to set this back to On and provide a decent error page when you deploy to a live server.